# Get the users who published the most photos (Descending Order)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I build my app model the same as AnyPic. i have photo that created by user . I want to create a query that will return the 100 users who published the most photos.

Comment: Then do exactly that. Or do you have any questions on how to perform the task?

Comment: You should try and solve it yourself first, and then if you have problems implementing it you can ask the SO community to help you find out what is wrong with your code, or even suggest better approaches. Keep in mind that SO is not a programming service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just the model from Anypic, you can't solve this with a query.

There are many paths that can get you there. One option would be to create a cloud function that keeps track of the number of published photos per user. Or you can create a cloud function that performs the necessary queries and calculations for you, so that the device doesn't have to do all that work.